# ESLint unexpected 'this' error in mongoose schema pre-save

Tags: express, mongoose, atom-editor, eslint, mongoose-schema

When calling the mongoose schema pre save on my model, I'm reassigning the '_id' value to 'id'.

Everything works as expected and the value is correctly assigned during save, however ESLint is triggering an error for the 'no-invalid-this' config parameter.

What can I do to remove this error without turning off the ESLint config?  Is there another way to reassign a value prior to saving the model without using 'this'?

Here is the code sample.

```
annotationSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.id = this._id;
    next();
});
```

ESLINT Error:
Severity: Error
Provider: ESLint
Description: Unexpected 'this'. (no-invalid-this)

Comment: Are you ok with disabling just this specific instance of the error?

Comment: I've turned it off for now, but I'd like to keep this setting in case there are other areas of my code where I do in fact violate the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable the single line for ESLint, adding the following, inline comment:

`this.id = this._id; // eslint-disable-line no-invalid-this`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great idea.  Thank you, I'll use this as the solution.